# SyntaxError on calculating sentiment data average from another file using Python Code

Tags: python

This program is written in Python3 in IDLE 3. Alright so this is the new code update and the error I have encountered is a ZeroDivisionError. This can be found in line 68 where it says the following:

**if (average / count) > 2:**

**This is the ERROR for the above statement encountered**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/angelajackson/Desktop/Movie_Part_2.py", line 68, in <module>
    if (average / count) > 2:
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

MY PROGRAM CODE BELOW:

```
import time
Start_Time = time.time()
#to store the words
sentimentData = {}

#opening the file for reviews
fileData = open('movie_reviews.rtf', 'r')

#Sotring all data into TotalData after converting the data into lowercase
TotalData = str.lower(fileData.read())
#file closing
fileData.close()

#split the data into lines by using newlinecharacter
reviewsData = TotalData.split('\n')

print('Initializing sentiment database')
#splitin the line into words by using space
for review in reviewsData:
    words = review.split(' ')

for word in words:
    if word not in sentimentData:
        try:
            sentimentData[word] = [1, int(float(words[0]))]
        except:
            print("Cannot convert this string to an integer")
    else:
        sentimentData[word][0] += 1
        sentimentData[word][1] += int(float(words[0]))
    

#doing the analysis on captured data
ending_time = time.time()

#time taken to read data
time = format(ending_time - Start_Time, '.2f')
#status what we are done
print('All Sentiment Data is taken from file and setups like a database')
print('Unique words are :', len(sentimentData))
print('For analyses taken time to compelte', time)
print('')

#asking the user to take phrase to enter phrase and converting to lower case and storing
phraseData = str.lower(input('Enter a phrase to test: '))
single_phrase = phraseData.split()

average = 0
count = 0

#count values to figure out the average score for the phrase
for word in single_phrase:
    if word in sentimentData:
        score = sentimentData[word][1] / sentimentData[word][0]
        print('* \'', word, '\' appears ', sentimentData[word][0], ' times with an average score of ', score, sep = '')
        average += score
        count += 1
    else:
        print('* \'', word, '\' does not appear in any movie reviews', sep = '')

#if no words appears
if count == 0:
    print('Not enough words to determine sentiment.')
else:
    print('Average score for this phrase is:', average / count)
#if average/count > 2 then it is a positive phrase
if (average / count) > 2:
    print('This is a POSITIVE phrase')
else:
    print('This is a NEGATIVE phrase')
```

Comment: Whichever code editor you use is irrelevant to such an error. Please provide relevant information such as an example fragment of your input file 'movie_review.txt'. Also which line is it that throws the error? Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: Line 52 is where the error occurs where it says: print('* \'', word, '\' appears ', sentimentData[word][0], ' times with an average score of ', score, sep = '')

Comment: So the syntax error occurs when you use python2. If you use python3 then the syntax error goes away. Just run `python3 your_script.py`. Post your complete error message with the line number that you get. Don't post images. This is bad practice.

Comment: **CODE HAS BEEN UPDATED** Ok, so I realized this program required a try and except function in order to work. After attempting this I encountered another error regarding ZeroDivisionError for the following statement in line 68: if (average / count) > 2:

Answer (score 1):

If the `count` is 0, then you don't want to calculate `average / count` since you'll get an error. So, just move your `if (average / count) > 2` inside the else:

```py
if count == 0:
    print('Not enough words to determine sentiment.')
else:
    print('Average score for this phrase is:', average / count)
    if average / count > 2:
        print('This is a POSITIVE phrase')
    else:
        print('This is a NEGATIVE phrase')
```